# hide header and footer on text files when direct print using win32 and python

Tags: python, text-files, pywin32, system.printing

I am stuck here when printing directly to text files using this code

```
win32api.ShellExecute (0, "print", "datafile.txt", None, ".", 0)
```

it always print the header "datafile.txt" and footer "Page1". I want to hide or remove this when printing on continous form paper. I do not want to install another third party software. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: why are you using windows api if python offers cross-platform modules for this?

Comment: which modules handling this method? can you suggest me the url?

Comment: first you'll have to explain exactly what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for reply @ BrainStorm. I have filename.txt with "Hello World" string. Then I need to print this file using python. But the ouput from printer comes with header with filename.txt and Page1 on footer. How to remove this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you're just a simple search away from finding a module that will handle this problem much better than this *hack* (e.g. use Reportlab and ShellExecute the PDF). Also, the default application for printing text files on Windows is Notepad. If you wish to configure the header/footer setting permanently, just change it in File->Page Setup.

If you wish to change Notepad's settings in your program, you can use the winreg module (`_winreg` in Python 2). However, there's a timing issue since ShellExecute doesn't wait for the job to be queued. Before restoring the old setting, you can either sleep for a little while or just wait for user `input` to continue. Here's a quick function that demonstrates the process:

```
try:
    import winreg
except:
    import _winreg as winreg
import win32api

def notepad_print(textfile, newset=None):
    if newset is not None: 
        oldset = {}
        hkcu = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
        notepad = winreg.OpenKey(hkcu, r'Software\Microsoft\Notepad', 0, 
                                 winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        for key, item in newset.items():
            oldset[key] = winreg.QueryValueEx(notepad, key)
            winreg.SetValueEx(notepad, key, None, item[1], item[0])

    #force printing with notepad, instead of using the 'print' verb
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'notepad.exe', '/p ' + textfile, '.', 0)

    input('once the job is queued, hit <enter> to continue')

    if newset is not None:
        for key, item in oldset.items():
            winreg.SetValueEx(notepad, key, None, item[1], item[0])
```

You can temporarily delete the header/footer settings with the following call:

```
notepad_print('datafile.txt', {'szHeader' : ('', 1), 'szTrailer': ('', 1)})
```

You can change as many of its registry settings as you want:

```
newset = {
  #name : (value, type)
  'lfFaceName': ('Courier New', 1), 
  'lfWeight': (700, 4),            #400=normal, 700=bold
  'lfUnderline': (0, 4), 
  'lfItalic': (1, 4),              #0=disabled, 1=enabled
  'lfStrikeOut': (0, 4), 
  'iPointSize': (160, 4),          #160 = 16pt
  'iMarginBottom': (1000, 4),      #1 inch
  'iMarginTop': (1000, 4), 
  'iMarginLeft': (750, 4), 
  'iMarginRight': (750, 4), 
  'szHeader': ('&f', 1),            #header '&f'=filename
  'szTrailer': ('Page &p', 1),      #footer '&p'=page number
}

notepad_print('datafile.txt', newset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [this method](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216640) seems to give more control to the programmer and certainly doesn't insert headers and foots without explicit statements.

Comment: @BrainStorm I mean like this one [http://computertipaday.blogspot.com/2009/03/remove-default-header-and-footer-from.html](http://computertipaday.blogspot.com/2009/03/remove-default-header-and-footer-from.html) but in python way.